# How to use Generics with Base Classes?

Tags: c#, .net

I am currently working with a base generic class, I will use it with simple data types such as strings, numbers, and more complex objects

```
public abstract class Base<T>
{
    protected T _value;
    public T GetValue => _value;

    public abstract ValueType Type { get; }
    public abstract void SetValue(T newValue);
}

public enum ValueType
{
    Text,
    Boolean
}
```

Here are some examples of how I implement the base class

```
public class Text : Base<string>
{
    public override ValueType Type => ValueType.Text;

    public override void SetValue(string newValue)
    {
        _value = newValue;
    }
}

public class Boolean : Base<bool>
{
    public override ValueType Type => ValueType.Boolean;

    public override void SetValue(bool newValue)
    {
        _value = newValue;
    }
}
```

Based on the ValueType, I need to initialize the corresponding implementation of the base class. However, I am unable to do it without specifying the generic type. The switch case cannot find the best type

```
var valueType = ValueType.Boolean;

Base obj = valueType switch
{
    ValueType.Text => new Text(),
    ValueType.Boolean => new Boolean(),
    _ => throw new NotSupportedException(),
};

obj.SetValue(false);
```

Is there any other way I can achieve this? I'm eager to explore all possible options and find the most efficient and effective solution

Comment: Well if you don't know what type it's going to be until runtime then how can you set it to `false`? What would that even mean?

Comment: @Charlieface I understand your point. I can eliminate the use of generics and instead use objects. Then, for each implementation, I can add specific types

Comment: `public class Base{} public class Base<T>:Base{}` now you have a non-generic type you can use for your variable. But you wont be able to call `.SetValue(bool)`.

Answer (score -1):

I switched from generics to objects and made some changes
here is how my base class looks now

```
public abstract class Base
{
    public abstract ValueType Type { get; }
    public abstract void SetValue(object newValue);
    public abstract object GetValue { get; }
}
```

I have decided to move the value with a specific type into the implementation

```
public class Text : Base
{
    public override ValueType Type => ValueType.Text;

    private string _value;

    public override void SetValue(object newValue)
    {
        _value = Convert.ToString(newValue);
    }

    public override object GetValue => _value;
}

public class Boolean : Base
{
    public override ValueType Type => ValueType.Boolean;

    private bool _value;

    public override void SetValue(object newValue)
    {
        _value = Convert.ToBoolean(newValue);
    }

    public override object GetValue => _value;
}
```

In this case, it works well for me

```
var valueType = ValueType.Boolean;
var obj = valueType switch
{
    ValueType.Text => new Text(),
    ValueType.Boolean => new Boolean(),
    _ => throw new NotSupportedException(),
};

obj.SetValue(false);
Console.WriteLine(obj.GetValue);
```

Comment: Well what's the point of generics then? And how would `Convert.ToWhatever` be correct, `false` and `"false"` are not the same thing

Comment: @Charlieface I think the main point here, is don't use generics at all

Comment: @Charlieface Using `Convert.To` was just an example. I can add any validation logic I need to the `SetValue` method for the received value